# Row Deselection Queries

Tags: excel, excel-2013

Help me out Excel aficionados, Google has failed me with this one ...

To select a number of non-contiguous rows in Excel I hold down Ctrl when I click on the row headers.  However if I want to unselect a row then holding down Ctrl and clicking on the header again has no effect.

Q1. Is there a way to unselect a row in this way?

In Excel 2013 when I attempt to deselect a row with Ctrl held down, the row remains selected but goes a little bit darker, and increasingly so if I click on it again.  This can leave somebody like me with multiple rows selected, but the appearance that some rows are more selected than others.

Q2. What is happening here?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Ans 1**. The answer to your 1st question is simple. Unfortunately you cant. Out of the box Excel doesn't support deselection via clicking for a second time. (Surprising how M'Soft didn't think about this)

You have some external 3rd party plugins ([Kutools](http://www.extendoffice.com/product/kutools-for-excel.html) for example) which does allow you to achieve it.

A workaround is writing a VBA script for the same, however that is kind of going over the edge.

**Ans 2**. Well I don't have excel 2013 so I can't help you with that one unfortunately. In 2010 it seemed to work pretty normal.